# ActionBar Style doesn't work

Tags: android, styles

I've put this in the Values\Styles.xml file:

```
<resources>

    <style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Light">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
    </style>

    <!-- ActionBar styles -->
    <style name="MyActionBar"
           parent="android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.Solid">
        <item name="android:background">@color/titlebgcolor</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/titletextcolor</item>
         <item name="android:textSize">40sp</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

I test it on android 4.0.4
This doesn't help as well:

```
ActionBar bar = getActionBar();
bar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(0x00AEEF));
```

Nothing in the item works (no change in color/bg/size)

Comment: have you declared Activity theme in manifest?

Comment: sure. it is there: <application
        android:icon="@drawable/logo"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

Comment: if I set the app theme to "MyActionBar" it works. but I want only the actionbar background style to change.

Comment: @Dani have you found any solution for this?